# I am writing a program which outputs the earliest date the user enter but some problems occurs

Tags: c

I am writing this program which prompt the user to enter a any number of dates and output the earliest when the user enter 0/0/0. But my program outputs the result after I input the first 2 dates. And when I enter more dates, it keeps comparing them but at the end, it gives a wrong result. Please help me fix it.
Here is my code

```
/*
//Input
Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): 3/6/08
Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): 5/17/07
Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): 6/3/07
Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): 0/0/0
//output
5/17/07 is the earliest date*/


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
int month, day, year;
int month2, day2, year2;
printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month2, &day2, &year2);

while(month != 0 && day != 0 && year != 0)
{
    printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
    scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);


    if(year == year2)
    {
        if(month == month2)
        {
            if(day > day2)
            {
                printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n", month2, day2, year2);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n",month, day, year);
            }
        }
        else if (month > month2)
        {
            printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n", month2, day2, year2);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n",month, day, year);
        }

    }
    else if(year > year2)
    {
        printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n", month2, day2, year2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n",month, day, year);
    }


} 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please add a copy-paste of the input session that you have with the program, i.e. what did the program display and what did you enter

Comment: When the user enters an earlier date than the first date, you need to replace `month`, `day`, and `year` with `month2`, `day2`, and `year2`. Then at the end, those variables will contain the earliest date.

Comment: So is there anything we can do to convince the C instructors of the world to (a) stop assigning exercises where the input is terminated by a dopey sentinels ("enter a series of numbers ending with -1") but rather by end-of-file like a real program, and (b) start teaching students to *look at the freaking return value of `scanf`*??

Comment: @SteveSummit Probably not, because those aren't critical to learning the basic principles of algorithms and programming, and will just confuse beginners even more.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

The first time `year, moth, day` are used, they lack initialization.

```
// int month, day, year;
int month = -1;
int day = 0;
int year = 0;
// ...
while(month != 0 && day != 0 && year != 0)
```

Otherwise OP is close, yet needs to change the earliest date as various new dates occur. [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492946/i-am-writing-a-program-which-outputs-the-earliest-date-the-user-enter-but-some-p#comment79940505_46492946).  Print the earliest date once, after the loop.

The loop exit condition test needs to occur right after data input.

```
while (1) {
  printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
  scanf("%d/%d/%d", &month, &day, &year);
  printf("%d/%d/%d is the date entered\n", month, day, year);
  if (!(month != 0 && day != 0 && year != 0)) {
    break;
  }

  int earlier = 0;
  if (year < year2) {
    earlier = 1;
  } else if (year == year2) {
    if (month < month2) {
      earlier = 1;
    } else if (month == month2) {
      if (day < day2) {
        earlier = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  if (earlier) {
    year2 = year; 
    month2 = month; 
    day2 = day;
  }
}

printf("%d/%d/%d is the earliest date\n", month2, day2, year2);
```

---

Other improvements include:

Reading a line of input and then parsing for a date.

Checking for scan errors.

Flush the output to insure the prompt  occurs before input.

```
printf("Enter a date (mm/dd/yy): ");
fflush(stdout);
```

Using better names.. Rather than `year2`, perhaps `early_year`?

A `do` loop rather than `while` one as the loop iterates at least once. Also then `month, day, year` can move to the inside of the loop.

Range checking for valid dates ...